# Object is possibly null error (typescript) when trying to display the value of an array which is stored in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint-config-airbnb, react-tsx

I'm currently creating a weather app where you can store your favorite locations which are pushed to an array, which in turn is stored in localstorage.

Now, I want to display the values of the array in a different component, but with my code I keep stumbling upon the error that the object is possible null.

```
export const FavoritesList: React.FC<any> = () => {
  // const storageFavorites = localStorage.getItem('favorites');
  const lsOutput = document.getElementById('lsOutput');
  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    const key: any = localStorage.key(i);
    const value: any = localStorage.getItem(key);
    // console.log(value);
    value.forEach(
      (item: any) => (lsOutput.innerHTML += `<li>${item}</li><br/>`)
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="lsOutput"></ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and it points specifically at lsOutput.innerHTML

What am I doing wrong?
I've currently assigned everything as any just to try to make it work first.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript is warning you that `getElementById` can return `null` (if there's no element with that ID). If you **know** that the element will exist, you an reassure TypeScript with a [non-`null` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions):

```
const lsOutput = document.getElementById('lsOutput')!;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

(But I don't think you do know that, see under the bar below.)

You'll have the same problem later with `value`. The analysis TypeScript does isn't deep enough to know that you're getting `key` from `localStorage.key(i)` and so you *know* `localStorage.getItem(key)` will return a non-`null` value. So again, you have to tell it that:

```
const value: any = localStorage.getItem(key)!;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

But there's another problem: `value.forEach` will never be defined in that code. `localStorage` **only** stores strings, not arrays, and strings don't have a `forEach` method.

When I want to store complex data in `localStorage`, I use JSON. For instance:

```
// Storing an array (or object)
localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(theArray);

// Retrieving:
const theArray = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
```

---

You're trying to work directly with the DOM within a React component, which is rarely necessary. When it is necessary, the way you're doing it isn't best practice (and won't work unless you already have a **different** element with the ID `lsOutput`, in which case you're creating a DOM with an invalid structure — you can't have two elements with the same `id` value). When your component function runs, the output you return from it won't be in the DOM yet.

Instead, do it the React way:

```
export const FavoritesList: React.FC<any> = () => {
  const items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    const key: any = localStorage.key(i);
    const value: any = localStorage.getItem(key);
    items.push(value);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'd also recommend using a single storage entry to hold that array of items, using JSON as shown above:

```
export const FavoritesList: React.FC<any> = () => {
  const items: string[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites"))!;
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It might also make sense not to go to local storage every time the component function is called; perhaps load the items in a parent component and pass them down as props.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to respond T.J. Crowder. I stressed too much trying to make this and just ended up staring blindly at the typescript error message, without realising that I should be doing it the react way of doing things. I see that you at first trusted that I knew what was even going on, and I'm sorry that my lack of knowledge and whirlwind of weird code  led you to try to solve something foolish.

Comment: @jrwebbie - No worries at all mate! Glad that helped. :-)